# Ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso with virt-manager-4.1.0.tar.gz install possible?

Tags: networking, 20.04, usb, kvm-virtualization

I have no Internet until I install a KVM router.

Therefore, I think I need Ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso to install from USB, with enough packages/libraries so that virt-manager-4.1.0.tar.gz will install successfully from a USB (copied off the USB onto the newly installed Ubuntu OS).

This should bring up the GUI for VMM 4.1.0, so I can then install the KVM router.iso from a USB.

Currently the following error appears:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Downloads/virt-manager-4.1.0$ ./virt-install 
ERROR    
--os-variant/--osinfo OS name is required, but no value was
set or detected.

This is now a fatal error. Specifying an OS name is required
for modern, performant, and secure virtual machine defaults.

You can see a full list of possible OS name values with:

   virt-install --osinfo list

If your Linux distro is not listed, try one of generic values
such as: linux2022, linux2020, linux2018, linux2016

If you just need to get the old behavior back, you can use:

  --osinfo detect=on,require=off

Or export VIRTINSTALL_OSINFO_DISABLE_REQUIRE=1
```